# Aptly publish snaphost can't find GPG key (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: package-management, gnupg

I'm attempting to publish a snapshot in aptly:
`aptly publish snapshot --architectures all myrelease-0.1`

It works if I specify --skip-signing.  But if I don't I get:

```
Loading packages...
Generating metadata files and linking package files...
Finalizing metadata files...
Signing file 'Release' with gpg, please enter your passphrase when prompted:
gpg: no default secret key: secret key not available
gpg: signing failed: secret key not available
ERROR: unable to publish: unable to detached sign file: exit status 2
```

I previously ran: `gpg --full-generate-key`, which successfully completed.

I'm thinking that aptly is looking for ~/.gnupg/secring.gpg, which is empty because gnupg 2.2 moved private keys into their own directory (private-keys-v1.d).  But not sure about this.

Anyone successfully get signing to work on Ubuntu 20.04, or 18.04?

Comment: My apologies - it is 20.04

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, take note, Aptly should be explicitly using gpg v1.x: https://www.aptly.info/doc/feature/pgp-providers/

You can generate your keys using `gpg1`, as your system may symlink the `gpg` command with `gpg2` executable.

---

As far as the keys being missing... for me I had a similar issue on Ubuntu 20.04:

I ended up having to declare everything regarding GPG explicitly in the publish command. I didn't use any "custom" keyrings when generating, just used GPG defaults, but Aptly didn't play nice with that.

Example (replace values with your values)...

```
aptly publish snapshot \
 -secret-keyring="secring.gpg" \
 -keyring="pubring.gpg" \
 -passphrase="myPassword" \
 -gpg-key="XYZ123" \
 -batch \
 -architectures="amd64" \
 -distribution=focal \
 foo
```

Once it's working you can start stripping down params until you narrow down what's breaking it. In my case I was using gpgv2 mixed with v1 and it was screwing things up reading the v2 generated keyring. After re-generating the key in v1, everything works with the defaults.

Param reference:

```
user@host1:~ # aptly publish help snapshot |grep GPG
Valid GPG key is required for publishing.
  -batch: run GPG with detached tty
  -gpg-key="": GPG key ID to use when signing the release
  -keyring=: GPG keyring to use (instead of default)
  -passphrase="": GPG passhprase for the key (warning: could be insecure)
  -passphrase-file="": GPG passhprase-file for the key (warning: could be insecure)
  -secret-keyring="": GPG secret keyring to use (instead of default)
  -skip-signing: don't sign Release files with GPG
```